# Matching patterns but witout some adpositions in Spacy

Tags: pattern-matching, spacy

I want to match patterns using the following pattern.
`pattern = [{'POS':'ADP'},{'POS':'ADJ','OP':'*'},{'POS':'NOUN'}]`
But I don't need results that have adpositions of 'to' and 'into'. I know that I can create a list with all the required adpositions and include it in the pattern. But I'm just wondering whether there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT_IN` to specify lists of items to exclude:

```py
pattern = [{"POS": "ADP", "LOWER": {"NOT_IN": ["to", "into"]}}]
```